# Can not locate object via package XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, csv

I'm trying to convert the xml file to csv using below script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new()->parsefile ( 'test.xml' );

print "id;name;description;published\n";
foreach my $row ( $twig->results->children('row') ) {        
        print join( ";",
            $row->first_child_text('id'),
            $row->first_child_text('name'),
            $row->first_child_text('description'),
            $row->first_child_text('published'),
),
            "\n";

}
```

But I'm getting error `Can't locate object method "`results" via package "XML::Twig" at perl1.pl line 10.

And here is my xml

```
<results>
  <row>
    <id></id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <published></published>
</row>
....
</result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tells you the problem - it's this line:

```
foreach my $row ( $twig->results->children('row') ) {
```

There is no 'results' method. You probably want:

```
foreach my $row ( $twig->root->children('row') ) {
```

the `root` method access the "document root" - which in this case is the "results" element of your XML.

You could also use `get_xpath` on `//row` to just find all the "row" elements anywhere in the doc.

As a style point - avoiding repetition as much as possible is desirable - so with that in mind, I'd suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @cols = qw ( id name description published );

my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile('test.xml');

print join( ";", @cols ), "\n";  #header row
foreach my $row ( $twig->get_xpath('//row') ) {
    print join( ";", map { $row->first_child_text($_) } @cols ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error Can't use string ("XML::Twig") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2/XML/Parser.pm line 224.
 at perl1.pl line 6.

Comment: OK. Can't answer why, without seeing some code. But ... have you got `use XML::Twig;` in your code? Because that's usually a sign of not having the module loaded.

Comment: Ask a new question, post the code and error. I'm sure someone will answer it (it may be me). I have tested the sample above, and that definitely works.